# PHP - require $file doesnt work - Failed opening required 'mod_login/.php'

Tags: php, require

first of all, thanks for your help.

I made a backend with /admin, you can enter these site with **mod_sitename.php**.

```
 $allowedForModul = checkAllowOfModuleByUserID(array('linkname' => 
 $_REQUEST['mod'], 'uid' => $_SESSION['s_user_id']));
     if ($allowedForModul OR in_array($_REQUEST['mod'], $allowedModules)) $file = "mod_" . $_REQUEST['mod'] . ".php";
     else $file = "mod_403.php";
```

Then I require the file with

```
 require $file;
```

**The Error:**

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'mod_login/.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /vagrant/admin/index.php on line
>   161 Call Stack

It's on PHP 7 with doctrine.

Comment: use require_once($file) instead of require $file

Comment: Echo out the value of `$_REQUEST['mod']` and see if it contains what it should contain. (Right now it looks like it contains `login/`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it appears the value of $_REQUEST['mod'] is "login/", therefore "mod" . $_REQUEST['mod'] . ".php" evaluates to "mod_login/.php".

Unless you have a folder called mod_login and a file in it called .php, the file won't be found.

Answer (score 0):

Seems `$_REQUEST['mod']` is not set, hence why it can't find `'/.php'`

if: `($allowedForModul` OR `in_array($REQUEST['mod'], $allowedModules))` is returning true and we know `$REQUEST['mod']` is null, then `$allowedForModu` must be returning true.

We'd need to see the content of the checkAllowOfModuleByUserID() method to have an idea of what is going on

Comment: Seems more like `$_REQUEST['mod']` is set, but set to `login/`.